# Why is my jqxhr.responseText variable undefined, when it's set in the xhr object?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a real simple jquery get call here, and I want to use the response later in the script. So if I do this:

```
var xhr = $.get('cfc/partsDefinition.cfc',{
                method: 'checkValid',
                search: 'some search string'
            }
        );
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

I can see that A) the first log shows a valid jqxhr object, with a responseText property set to what I expect...

```
promise: function (a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a}
readyState: 4
responseText: "0"
setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this}
```

but B) the second log shows "undefined". What am I missing here?

Comment: Your specific technical point does sound a bit odd, but I guess the question is.... why do you need it at that point?  Since you're making an asynchronous request, the value you'll want to work with won't be available yet, and only will be available within a callback function (which I see you have not provided).

Comment: I'm new enough to using ajax to be dangerous, I guess... I had tried using a callback function to assign the response contents to a js variable but had forgotten about the ramifications of the asynchronous part of ajax. So I HAVE to either use the response variable inside the callback OR use an asynchronous call... which I've tried but get unexpected results for the responseText (an html page named "Component Browser Login" which includes a form to "Enter your RDS or Admin password below"). Seems like a different question to post.

Comment: p.s. having said all that, I still don't understand why console.log shows a valid, fully formed xhr object, but the following log of xhr.responseText shows undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is showing `undefined` because at that point in the code, it IS undefined. AJAX is Asynchronous, meaning it doesn't complete before code after it get's ran. The `responseText` will be undefined until the ajax call is complete. Here's an example:

```
var xhr = $.get('cfc/partsDefinition.cfc',{
                method: 'checkValid',
                search: 'some search string'
            }
        ).done(function(data){
            console.log("xhr",xhr);
            console.log("xhr.responseText",xhr.responseText);
            console.log("data",data);
        });
console.log("This should happen before the other console logs");
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed - you're probably dumping it when it's not there; try adding some error handling:

```
        $.get('cfc/partsDefinition.cfc',{
                method: 'checkValid',
                search: 'some search string'
            },
            function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ // Success Case
                console.log(data);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        );

        $('.errorContainer').ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError){
                    $(this).append('ohhhhz noooz - ajax error');
            console.log(event);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(ajaxSettings);
            console.log(thrownError);
        });
```

In jQuery the `get()` shorthand doesn't have any built in error handling - it just supresses it. So if you're trying to catch something you need to make your own error handlers.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/